# Unique Id of a program in runtime

Tags: c#

I'd like to have a unique Id for all the instances of my software that is running. What is the best way to get such an Id in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a Global Unique Identifier

```
var id = Guid.NewId();
```

Answer (score 0):

Without more information, the simplest solution I could give is `Guid uniqueId = Guid.NewGuid()`.

To make a sensible decision, you need to know:

- How unique does it need to be? Unique at any single point in time? Unique for all time?
- What's your criteria for "best"? Fastest to generate? Universally unique? Easiest for the user to remember when it's displayed to them?